# Mostrar application/json

Tags: php, json, jsonarray, jsonp

Buenas tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
     <?php 
        $valor = '1';
        echo "<script>
               var imgurl = 'https://midominio.com/img/$valor';
               var MyObjt = {
            name: name,
            description: description,
            image: imgurl,  
            atributes: [{
                Category: category,
                Store: store,
                Theme: theme

            }]
        }

       jsonStr = JSON.stringify(MyObjt);
       document.body.innerHTML = jsonStr;
       </script>";
       ?>
```

El output de esto es un objeto json:

```
       {"name":"my name","description":"description goes 
       here","image":"https://midominio.com/img/1.png","atributes": 
       [{"Category":"Categoria","Store":"tienda","Theme":"Comon"}]}
```

El problema es que necesito que este archivo sea leido por un archivo externo, el cual pide que la aplicacion este codificada en formato json, pero al colocar los header json me muestra todo el codigo de la pagina y no el objeto json.

Como puedo mostrar la respuesta de forma compatible Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8 y que preserve la estructura de la forma en que la tengo, ya que uso los datos que estan antes del objeto creado.

De antemano muchas gracias

Agrego el codigo que estoy usando:

```
     <?php
     if (isset($_GET['PATH_INFO'])){
     $req = explode('/', $_GET['PATH_INFO']);
     #Obtenemos cómo termina la URL
     $endPoint = array_shift($req);
     $img = resolve('img/' .$endPoint);
     echo" 
     <script language='javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.36/dist/web3.min.js'></script>
     <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
     <script src='../js/abi.js'></script>
     <script>

        async function getDetais() {

        if(typeof web3 !== 'undefinied'){
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            web3 = new Web3(new web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws/v3/73dc6da57d3d489bbb31af8f2bd2625c'));
        }
        const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(myABI, 'MYCONTRACT');
        //Aqui uso el php que recibi arriba
        const tkndetails = await myContract.methods._getDToken($endPoint).call();
        const tkndetails2 = await myContract.methods._getDTokenDetails($endPoint).call();
        //aqui recibo un array, no se como modificarlo y por eso lo desgloso abajo
        //este arreglo imprime:
        // {"0":"nombre", "1":"descripcion"...etc}
        // La aplicacion externa espera los datos tipo: 
        // {"nombre":"mi_nombre", "descripcion":"mi_descripcion"...etc}
        // contenido de la primera consulta
        const name = tkndetails[1];
        const descr = tkndetails[2];
        //contenido de la segunda consulta
        const dato3 = tkndetails2[0];
        const dato4 =tkndetails2[1];
        const dato5 =tkndetails2[2];
        const dato6 =tkndetails2[3];
        const dato7 =tkndetails2[4];
        //tomo la variable php para hacer la busqueda de la imagen y agregar todo a un nuevo objeto json
        var imgurl = 'https://midominio.com/api/$img';
        var MyObjt = {
            name: nombre,
            description: descr,
            image: imgurl,  
            atributes: [{
                dato1: dato1,
                dato2: dato2,
                dato3: dato3,
                dato4: dato4,
                dato5: dato5,    
            }]
        }
     //trato de imprimirlo en formato json, de tal manera que la aplicacion externa pueda obtener los datos
     jsonStr = JSON.stringify(MyObjt);
     document.body.innerHTML = jsonStr;
     console.log(jsonStr);
    }

    getDetais();

   </script>";
   }; ?>
```

Es la unica forma que consegui para obtener los datos de forma externa sin tener que recurrir a una base de datos local, sin embargo, la aplicacion que revisa la api debe ver la data encodeada en json. Al hacerle el encode simplemente me muestra todo el codigo y la aplicacion externa no lee la data. Ademas cuando lo coloco en json no me muestra la data (imagino que es por que no se ejecuta nada y muestra literal lo que hay ahi)

Comment: Puedes mostrarme el script donde estas poniendo los headers para que PHP codifique la aplicación?

Comment: El header lo coloco justo antes de la etiqueta php. Solo coloco <? header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8"); ?>  de esa forma la aplicación externa tiene acceso a la data, si aplico otra cosa simplemente se me muestra el codigo y la aplicación externa no lee nada

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el problema está en que estás desplegando el JSON dentro de la etiqueta body del HTML. Lo mejor es usar una etiqueta `<pre>`:

```
var data = {
  "data": {
    "x": "1",
    "y": "1",
    "url": "http://url.com"
  },
  "event": "start",
  "show": 1,
  "id": 50
}


document.getElementById("json").textContent = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);

<pre id="json"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

En base a la respuesta que compartes en los comentarios parace ser que estas confundiendo una parte fundamental del desarrollo servicios JSON en PHP.

En este caso tu código PHP no debe mezclarse con JavaScript, para generar el servicio que publicará los datos, tu programa por tanto debe tener un **service.php** escrito 100% en código del lado Servidor (PHP).

¿Cual es tu problema entonces?
Cuando ejecutas el programa en tu comtadora estas recibiendo una respuesta con código JavaScript que generó PHP, tu navegador como entiende Javascript lo renderiza correctamente ejecutandolo pero ya del lado cliente.

Como solventar el problema de la siguiente manera:

**service.php**

```php
<?php 
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
$valor = '1';
$imgurl = 'https://midominio.com/img/$valor';
$data = array(
    "name" => "Tu nombre aqui",
    "description" => "tu descripcion aqui",
    "image" => $imgurl,  
    "atributes" => array(
        array(
            "Category" => "Categoria",
            "Store" => "Tu tienda",
            "Theme" => "Tu tema"
        )
    )
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

De esta manera tu service.php generará el texto en Json y cualquier programa podrá acceder a él sin la necesidad de entender código JavaScript.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: El problema con este codigo es que el valor lo estoy recibiendo de una consulta realizada a traves de el java, es por ello que uso java y php. Yo estoy consultando un contrato ethereum y estoy recibiendo la data en java, con esa data debo hacer una consulta en php y devolver la respuesta en json. Seria algo asi: recibo la data y la proceso con php, envio la consulta por medio del java y recibo un objeto, el cual debo modificar y mostrar en json

Comment: Y para hacer la búsqueda del contrato puedes cambiar de Web Sockets a REST(HTTP) o SOAP? Porque puedes hacer un service independiente y otro que mantenga el código que tienes.

Comment: Las otras opciones que veo son hacer la conexión al Web Socket utilizando el cliente que describe https://diego.com.es/sockets-en-php ese sitio, y sustituir la petción ajax con cURL desde PHP. Si no tendrías que buscar crear un flujo de pasos en el que se vaya obteniendo la información que necesitas para el otro paso de forma independiente.